# Scheduled entity in onFlush is different instance

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a strange problem with `\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::getScheduledEntityDeletions` used inside `onFlush` event

```
foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entity) {
    if ($entity instanceof PollVote) {
        $arr = $entity->getAnswer()->getVotes()->toArray();

        dump($arr);
        dump($entity);

        dump(in_array($entity, $arr, true));
        dump(in_array($entity, $arr));
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image: dump() output]

So we see that the object is pointing to a different instance than the original, therefore `in_array` no longer yields expected results when used with stick comparison (AKA `===`). Furthermore, the `\DateTime` object is pointing to a different instance.

The only possible explanation I found is the following ([source](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html#how-doctrine-detects-changes)):

> Whenever you fetch an object from the database Doctrine will keep a copy of all the properties and associations inside the UnitOfWork. Because variables in the PHP language are subject to “copy-on-write” the memory usage of a PHP request that only reads objects from the database is the same as if Doctrine did not keep this variable copy. Only if you start **changing** variables PHP will **create new variables internally** that consume new memory.

However, I did not change anything (even the `created` field is kept as it is). The only operations that were preformed on entity are:

1. `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findBy` (fetching from DB)
2. `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager::remove` (scheduling for removal)
3. `$em->flush();` (triggering synchronization with DB)

Which leads me to think (I might be wrong) that the Doctrine's change tracking method has nothing to do with the issue that I'm experiencing. Which leads me to following questions:

- What causes this?
- How to reliably check if an entity scheduled for deletion is inside a collection (`\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection::contains` uses `in_array` with strict comparison) or which items in a collection are scheduled for deletion?

Comment: Looks like I've faced similar issue today. Do you remove your entity explicitly? Or it is removed by cascade?

Comment: @AndreyMischenko `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager::remove` is called on the entity in question. No cascades are involved in my case

Comment: @AndreyMischenko did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you tell doctrine to remove entity, it is removed from identity map ([here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1324)):

```
<?php

public function scheduleForDelete($entity)
{
    $oid = spl_object_hash($entity);

    // ....

    $this->removeFromIdentityMap($entity);

    // ...

    if ( ! isset($this->entityDeletions[$oid])) {
        $this->entityDeletions[$oid] = $entity;
        $this->entityStates[$oid]    = self::STATE_REMOVED;
    }
}
```

And when you do `$entity->getAnswer()->getVotes()`, it does the following:

1. Load all votes from database
2. For every vote, checks if it is in identity map, use old one
3. If it is not in identity map, create new object

Try to call `$entity->getAnswer()->getVotes()` before you delete entity. If the problem disappears, then I am right. Of cause, I would not suggest this hack as a solution, just to make sure we understand what is going on under the hood.

**UPD** instead of `$entity->getAnswer()->getVotes()` you should probably do foreach for all votes, because of lazy loading. If you just call `$entity->getAnswer()->getVotes()`, Doctrine probably wouldn't do anytning, and will load them only when you start to iterate through them.

Comment: You are right. Initializing the collection before removal fixes the issue. But it also removes the deleted item from the collection. This means that I cannot trust the collection in the listener as it doesn't know if it was initialized or not....

Comment: In any case, you found the cause of the problem so you win the bounty

Comment: @Xymanek You should probably use preRemove event or something like that. You didn't share your usecase, so it is hard to suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html):

> If you call the EntityManager and ask for an entity with a specific ID twice, it will return the same instance

So calling twice `findOneBy(['id' => 12])` should result in two exact same instances.

So it all depends on how both instances are retrieved by Doctrine. 
In my opinion, the one you get in $arr is from a One-to-Many association on $votes in the Answer entity, which results in a separate query (maybe a `id IN (12)`) by the ORM.

Something you could try is to declare this association as EAGER (`fetch="EAGER"`), it may force the ORM to make a specific query and keep it in cache so that the second time you want to get it, the same instance is returned ?

Could you have a look at the logs and post them here ? It may indicates something interesting or at least relevant to investigate further.

Comment: The collection of votes (`getAnswer()->getVotes()`) is not initialized before being dumped to array - perhaps this has something to do with the problem. I'm playing with a reduced test case now, will report back when I have a good set of results